# Formatação de valores de gráfico usando Syncfusion para Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin-forms

Estou usando o `Syncfusion` para criar gráficos em `Xamarin Forms`.

Estudando a [documentação](https://help.syncfusion.com/xamarin/sfchart/working-with-data), não consegui achar uma forma para formatar os valores do meu gráfico, exemplo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Quero esses valores formatados para moeda brasileira : **Outubro - R$ 14.421,52**

Alguém sabe como posso fazer isso?

Minha page em **XAML**:

```
<chart:SfChart.Series>
    <chart:BarSeries ItemsSource="{Binding PieSeriesData}" Color="Red" XBindingPath="Name" YBindingPath="Value" LegendIcon="Rectangle" Label="Valor (R$)" EnableAnimation="True">
        <chart:BarSeries.DataMarker>
            <chart:ChartDataMarker LabelContent="YValue" ShowLabel="True">
                <chart:DataMarkerLabelStyle LabelFormat="R$##,##" LabelPosition="Center"/>
            </chart:ChartDataMarker>
        </chart:BarSeries.DataMarker>
    </chart:BarSeries>
</chart:SfChart.Series>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Em contato com o suporte do *Syncfusion:*

> Você pode atingir esse requisito, definindo um DataTemplate com um
>   IValueConverter para o marcador de dados e usando a propriedade
>   ChartDataMarker.LabelTemplate. Consulte o seguinte trecho de código
>   para obter mais detalhes.

*DateTemplate:*

```
<ResourceDictionary >    
 <local: DataMarkerConverter x:Key="labelConverter"></local: DataMarkerConverter>     
  <DataTemplate x:Key="LabelTemplate">     
    <StackLayout>    
        <Label Text="{Binding YValue, Converter={StaticResource labelConverter}"/>     
    </StackLayout>    
  </DataTemplate>    
</ResourceDictionary>
```

*Conversor:*

```
public class DataMarkerConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        double yValue = System.Convert.ToDouble(value);
        return yValue.ToString("#,###.##", new CultureInfo("pt-BR"));
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return value;
    }
}
```

Comment: Seria interessante que você compartilhasse a resposta com a comunidade, caso tenha encontrado uma. Compartilhar apenas um link exige que o conteúdo externo esteja disponível, aliás, nesse caso inclusive, exige autenticação (cadastro no site) e possivelmente só será visível para você, que registrou o incidente.

Comment: Essa resposta implica login. Podes juntar à resposta o que foi dito nesse link?

Comment: Irei preparar e melhorar essa resposta. até amanha 29-10-17 já estará disponível uma resposta mais detalhada sobre esse assunto, obrigado pelo feedback.

Comment: @samuelrvg conseguiu escrever a resposta mais detalhada?

Comment: Perdão, me esqueci, irei fazer agora e postar.